# merge excel cells via VB.NET without asking when every cell has a value

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a VB.NET website and I am organizing some data in excel file. 
I need to merge cells which have same data in excel but everytime I try to this operation, program stops and shows this notification:

[image]

I don't want to see it and I want program to continue without asking. Is it possible, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have something like

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
```

somewhere in your code. If so, then all you need to do is put the line

```
oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

before you try merging, and then set it back to true afterwords for safety.

If not, please post some of your code and I'll help you out further. This DOES work, though.  I've done it before.

Comment: Ah, I think I know the problem. Editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do this manually, and answer OK, then all the data except the data from the top-left cell would be lost.

Why do you not clear the other cells before merging?

Comment: I don't want to click ok everytime because excel file dimension may be big. Inside of excel file is like that :
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/55978766.jpg/ So, I need to merge cells which have same content

Comment: Again, why do you not: 1) Identify the cells you want to merge. 2) Clear the content of all but the upper-left cell. 3) Merge the cells. You will end up with the same result, but with no dialog box. You could also use the DisplayAlerts setting, as the other solution offered, but that is a global setting, and may suppress other alerts that you do want.

Comment: It won't suppress anything as long as you set it back to true immediately afterwords.  When doing automation, it is often best to set DisplayAlerts to false for a number of reasons, including saving, closing, etc.  Just be sure to set it to true on EVERY situation that will cause your program to exit.

Comment: Yeah, but that has the stench of "On Error Resume Next" about it, and I really don't ever want to see that again.  You should only suppress an alert that you expect, not all alerts.  Since you can't do that in Excel, (I feel) it's better to address the conditions that raise the alerts you expect in code.  My opinion - probably not worth the bandwidth it took to download this comment.